# Does register_shutdown_function() get called before or after the response is echoed?

Tags: php, phalcon

I am writing a Phalcon PHP application. In it, I register a shutdown function in the constructor of a class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'shutdownHandler']);
}

public function shutdownHandler()
{
    $this->deliverQueue();
}
```

Whenever the conditions for it to run hold, the waiting time for the response is higher.

I made a small test: When I comment out the `deliverQueue`, response comes back in one second. When I replace this line with a sleep(1), response comes back after 5-6(!!!) seconds. When I replace with a sleep(10), 500 error.

Per the documentation, I would expect the shutdown function to activate **after** script execution finishes, therefore **after** the response gets echoed back.

Is the documentation incorrect? Why is this happening?

Comment: Did my best to make the sentences cohesive.  Enhanced formatting and question title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `register_shutdown_function` Execute after script finishes or if any attempt of `exit` or even if any `error` occurs `register_shutdown_function` will run